# How to remove the word Listing from the caption of the code and write it below the code?

Tags: captions, listings

How to remove the word "Listing" from my TeX file?

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx,listings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={1},language=Python]
    if(a==b):
        print 2
    
    \end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}
```

If we compile the above code, I get "Listing 1: 1". But I dont want to write the caption as "Listing 1: 1". I want to write it as "Code 1: 1".
I also want to make the caption appear below the code.
However, I cant make these two things happen. What shall i do?

Can someone please help me to fix the two issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `\lstlistingname` to be `Code` and set `captionpos=b`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{captionpos=b}
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Code}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={1},language=Python]
    if(a==b):
        print 2
\end{lstlisting}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, You are incredible dear,  Love you!!